# How exactly do "Objects communicate with each other by passing messages"?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop

In several introductory texts on Object-oriented programming, I've come across the above statement.

From wikipedia, "In OOP, each object is capable of **receiving messages**, processing data, and **sending messages** to other objects and can be viewed as an independent 'machine' with a distinct role or responsibility."

What exactly does the statement mean in code?

```
class A
{ 
    methodA()
    {

    }
}


class B
{
    methodB()
    {

    }
}


class C
{
    main()
    {
        A a=new A();
        B b=new B();
        a.methodA(); // does this mean msgs passing??
        b.methodB(); // or does this?? I may be completely off-track here..
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for one, you can't call a.methodB() because a is an instance of A, and class A only defines methodA(). So that won't compile in any language I know of.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this was an error.

Comment: Please open class brackets after class name. In same line.

like this:

class C {

}

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If we are talking about OOP than the term "message passing" comes from [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk). In a few words the Smalltalk basic principles are:

1. *Object* is the basic unit of object-oriented system.
2. Objects have their own *state*.
3. Objects communicate by sending and receiving *messages*.

If you are interested in Smalltalk take a look at [Pharo](http://www.pharo-project.org/home) or [Squeak](http://www.squeak.org/).

Java/C#/C++ and many other languages use slightly different approach probably derived from [Simula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula). You *invoke a method* instead of pass a message.

I think this terms are more or less equivalent. May be the only interesting difference is that message passing (at least in Smalltalk) always rely on dynamic dispatch and late binding while in the case of method invocation one can use static dispatch and early binding too. For example, C++ (AFAIK) does early binding by default until "virtual" keyword appears somewhere...

Anyway, regardless of which formalism do your programming language use for communication between two objects (message passing or method invocation) it's always considered a good OOP style to forbid direct access to instance variables in Smalltalk terminology or data members in C++ terminology or whatever term is used in your programming language.

Smalltalk directly prohibits access to instance variables at the syntax level. As I mentioned above objects in Smalltalk program can interact only by passing/receiving messages. Many other languages allow access to instance variables at the syntax level but it's considered a bad practice. For example, the famous [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) book contains the corresponding recommendation: Item 22: Declare data members private.

The reasons are:

- syntactic consistency (the only way for clients to access an object is via member functions or message passing);
- more precise control over the accessibility of data members (you can implement no access, read-only access, read-write access, and even write-only access);
- you can later replace the data member without breaking your public interface.

The last one is the most important. It's the essence of *encapsulation* - information hiding on the class level.

> The point about encapsulation is more important than it might initially appear. If you hide your data members from your clients (i.e., encapsulate them), you can ensure that class invariants are always maintained, because only member functions can affect them. Furthermore, you reserve the right to change your implementation decisions later. If you don't hide such decisions, you'll soon find that even if you own the source code to a class, your ability to change anything public is extremely restricted, because too much client code will be broken. Public means unencapsulated, and practically speaking, unencapsulated means unchangeable, especially for classes that are widely used. Yet widely used classes are most in need of encapsulation, because they are the ones that can most benefit from the ability to replace one implementation with a better one.

(с) Scott Meyers, Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs (3rd Edition)

Comment: In c++,java,C#, invoking a method itself implies mesage passing i guess.

Comment: @Zaki: I edited my answer to clarify some points. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but a little digression about **message dispatch vs. method invocation**:

The term *message* refers to the fact that you don't know *which* method will be invoked due to polymorphism. You *ask* an object to do something (hence the term *message*) and it acts accordingly.  The term method *invocation* is misleading as it suggest you pick one exact method.

The term *message* is also closer to the reality of dynamic language, where you could actually send a message that the object doesn't understand (see `doesNotUnderstand` in Smalltalk). You can then not really speak of method invocation given that there is none matching, and the message dispatch will fail. In static typed language, this problem is prevented.

Answer (score 9):

**"Passing a message" is an abstraction.**

Most OO languages today implement that abstraction in the form of feature invocation. By feature I mean <strike>a method</strike> an operation (see edit below), property or something similar. Bertrand Meyer in [OOSC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Oriented_Software_Construction) argues that feature invocation is the basic unit of computation in modern OO languages; this is a perfectly valid and coherent way to implement the old abstract idea that "objects communicate by message passing".

Other implementation techniques are possible. For example, objects managed by some middleware systems communicate by passing messages via a queue facility.

In summary: don't confuse abstractions with code. In the olden days, programmers used to care a lot about theory because programming barely existed as a mainstream profession. Today, most programmers are rarely familiar with the theory behind the code. :-)

By the way, and for the theory inclined, agent-oriented modelling and programming approaches often emphasise message passing as a communication mechanism between agents, arguing that it derives from [speech act theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act_theory). No method invocation is involved here.

**Edit**. In most OO languages, you call operations rather than methods. It is the runtime engine which decides which particular method to invoke as a response to the operation that you have called. This enables the implementation of the so often mentioned mechanisms of polymorphism. This little nuance is usually forgotten in routine parlance when we refer to "calling a method". However, it is necessary in order to differentiate between *operations* (as features that implement message passing) and *methods* (as specific versions of said operations).

Answer (score 8):

They're referring to the fact that a client can invoke a method on a receiving object, and pass data to that object, but that object can decide autonomously what to do with that data, and maintain its own state as required.

The client object can't manipulate the state of the receiving object directly. This is an advantage of *encapsulation* - the receiving object can enforce its own state independently and change its implementation without affecting how clients interact with it.

Comment: Agreed in principle, although in everyday use I would say that the term "message passing" has a more specific meaning, i.e. the way it is used in Smalltalk. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing

Comment: "a client can invoke a method on a receiving object, and pass data to that object.." pass data as in pass parameters to that method, and the method definition decides what to do with the passed data. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

In OOP, objects don't necessarily communicate with each other by passing messages. They communicate with each other in *some* way that allows them to specify what they want done, but leaves the implementation of that behavior to the receiving object. Passing a message is one way of achieving that separation of the interface from the implementation. Another way is to call a (virtual) method in the receiving object.

As to which of your member function calls would really fit those requirements, it's a bit difficult to say on a language-agnostic basis. Just for example, in Java member functions are virtual by default, so your calls to `a.methodA()` and `b.methodB()` would be equivalent to passing a message. Your (attempts a) calls to `b.methodA()` and `a.methodB()` wouldn't compile because Java is statically typed.

On the contrary, in C++, member functions are *not* virtual by default, so none of your calls is equivalent to message passing. To get something equivalent, you'd need to explicitly declare at least one of the member functions as virtual:

```
class A { 
    virtual void methodA() {}
};
```

As it stands, however, this is basically a "distinction without a difference." To get some idea of what this means, you need to use some inheritance:

```
struct base { 
    void methodA() { std::cout << "base::methodA\n"; }
    virtual void methodB() { std::cout << "base::methodB\n"; }
};

struct derived { 
    void methodA() { std::cout << "derived::methodA\n"; }
    virtual void methodB() { std::cout << "derived::methodB"; }
};

int main() { 
    base1 *b1 = new base;
    base2 *b2 = new derived;

    b1->methodA();   // "base::methodA"
    b1->methodB();   // "base::methodB"
    b2->methodA();   // "base::methodA"
    b2->methodB();   // "derived::methodB"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have posted will not compile in any oop language, as `methodB` does not belong to object `A` and `methodA` doesn't belong to object `B`.

If you called the correct method, then both of these are message passing by object `C`:

```
a.methodA();
b.methodB();
```

From wikipedia:

`The process by which an object sends data to another object or asks the other object to invoke a method.`

Comment: And b doesn't have methodA()! =)

Answer (score 2):

Your example won't work with Java or Python, so I have corrected and annotated your main

```
class C{
  main()
  {
   A a=new A();
   B b=new B();
   a.methodA(); // C says to a that methodA should be executed
   // C says to b that methodB should be executed
   // and b says to C that the result is answer
   answer = b.methodB(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of the early academic work on OO was in terms of objects passing messages to each other in order to invoke behavior. Some early OO languages were actually written that way (SmallTalk?).

Modern languages like C++, C# and Java do not work that way at all. They simply have code call methods on objects. This is exactly like a procedural language, except that a hidden reference to the class being called is passed in the call ("`this`").

Answer (score 2):

passing object as parameter to a method of an object that belong to a different class type.
this way you pass attribute of an object to another object of a different class
just call  an methods of a object  of an other class.
so you can create an object of this class to get information of other object of different class.
Note:
 this no override methods ok because they can be the same name but belong to a different class type.
override methods is went you heritage a methods in a sub class and you change the behavior of the same methods that you get for heritance of a super class.
the method to call is depending of arguments that you put in the method or the data type. the system call the right  method and they can be located in a object of a superclass or in a object of a subclass.

a lot of people ask the same question. when they are working with OOP.
I recommend read those old books. 
to understand what is OOP and not learn to programming object oriented in a programming language as  CPP, JAVA and PHP.
introduction to OOP (Timothy Buud)
Object-Oriented Programming: An Evolutionary Approach
 (Brad J Cox . Andrew J Novobilski)
and not forget to read Bjarne stroustrup CPP new books.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Car{
string brand;   
public:
void setBrand(string newBrand){this->brand=newBrand;}
void Driver(){cout<<" IS DRIVING THIS CAR BRAND "<<brand<<endl;}
void Brake(){cout<<"IS BRAKING"<<endl;}
};

class Person{
private:string name;
public:
void setName(string newName){this->name=newName;}
//HERE WE CALL METHOD OF CAR CLASS AND REDEFINE METHODS NO OVERRIDE OK   
void Driver(Car objectOfClassCar){cout<<this->name<<ends;  
objectOfClassCar.Driver();}
 void Brake(string str, Car objectOfClassCar){cout<<this->name<<"  
"<<str<<ends;objectOfClassCar.Brake();}
  };

  int main(){
  Car corolla;
  corolla.setBrand("TOYOTA");   
  Person student;
  student.setName("MIGUEL");
  student.Driver(corolla);
  student.Brake("CAR",corolla);
  //it open a lot of opportunities to do the same.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does that code works?

Anyway you're out of the road...

Message passing is a way for interprocess communication, one among many others. It means that two (or more) object can only speak one each other by messaging, which should say from who, to who, and what...

You can see it's very different from shared memory, for example...

Comment: I've also seen other texts use the term "message passing" when talking about OO, although I've never heard that here or from other programmers. I think it was a terminology used early in the OO days.

Comment: No. Message passing is general OO practice. Take a look at Smalltalk.

Comment: The OP is trying to understand OOP.

Comment: Right. I never heard about message-passing in OO programming!

Comment: From what I've studied, "message passing" refers to a perspective taken by Smalltalk and Objective-C (whose design was heavily influenced by Smalltalk). In these languages, objects are sent messages via the following syntax:
[myObject aMessage:aParameter];
Which is synonymous to (in Java for example):
myObject.aMessage(aParameter);
In Objective-C you are "sending a message" while in Java you are "calling and instance method"

Comment: thats what i thought, instances of classes calling instance methods, as simple as that.

Comment: @Mark S, you should probably have your comment as an answer, it really lays it out straight, certainly helpful, so that I could +1.